# Obtain Worksheet COMObject in Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

I have been trying to add pushbuttons to dynamically created excel sheets using win32com from inside python. The main problem i am facing is that i am unable to obtain the Worksheet COMObject on which i can apply the Worksheet methods. I have got the following code so far:

```
from win32com.client import DispatchEx, Dispatch
excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('some/path/')
ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
print(ws)
ws.Buttons.Add(786, 323.25, 109.5, 29.25)
```

This gives the following one output and one error:

```
<COMObject Add>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Add'
```

I was expecting that 'ws' to be a worksheet COMObject on which i can directly add a pushbutton using the code above. Kindly explain to me what i'm doing wrong here as well as a method to obtain Worksheet object on which the above code snippet would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ws.Buttons` is a method that returns a COMObject when called. So you need to add parentheses directly after it.

```
from win32com.client import DispatchEx, Dispatch
excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('some/path/')
ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()

# Show the difference between `ws.Buttons` and `ws.Buttons()`
print(type(ws.Buttons))
print(type(ws.Buttons()))

# Add button to worksheet
ws.Buttons().Add(786, 323.25, 109.5, 29.25)
```